# Mac OSX: How to stroke text in NSTextField?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've programming an application for the OSX using Objective C. I have an NSTextField that I'm using to display uneditable text. I'm trying to make the font have a thin stroke/outline around it but struggling to do so.

I've tried to use NSTextView instead of NSTextField and implemented an NSAttributedString as so, however the text is not being outlined at all:

```
            NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Test String" attributes:@{ NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [CIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [CIColor blackColor], NSStrokeWidthAttributeName : @-1.0 }];

            [quoteText_Label setEditable:YES];
            [quoteText_Label insertText: string];
            [quoteText_Label setEditable:NO];
```

Looking at the other question of SO, they're either aimed at iOS, Swift, or are an overkill for the simple implementation I'm attempting to go for: just a simple black stroke around white font.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch on Rich Text in the XIB and set the `attributedStringValue` property of the text field. You don't have to do `setEditable`.

Read the documentation of `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName`:

> NSNumber containing floating point value, as percent of font point size
>
> Default 0, no stroke; positive, stroke alone; negative, stroke and fill (a typical value for outlined text would be 3.0)

A thin black outline around black text is hardly visible.

Answer (score 0):

Values of the color attributes should be NSColor objects. I think, using CIColor is wrong here.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.